# How to move file one by one to folder after succesfully inserted data to table of particular file in SSIS?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have used File System task for this.But Using File System Task,all files are moved together ,after data of all files is inserted in table .

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: I want to store each log file data to db.When data is fully inserted in table i want to move that file to another folder.Using precedence constraint and file system task all files are moved together after data of all files are inserted.

Comment: My question is :Is it possible to move file one by one after inserting data of file to db in SSIS?

Comment: You need to google harder https://help.sentryone.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20loop%20through%20files%20in%20a%20specified%20folder,%20load%20one%20by%20one%20and%20move%20to%20archive%20folder%20using%20SSIS.htm  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Just create separate packages to move files one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively get each file from the File System like in the code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CheckFileSizes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int FILE_SIZE_CHECK = 10000000;
        const int FILE_COUNT_CHECK = 10000;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"c:\temp";
            textBoxTotalFolderSizeMin.Text = FILE_SIZE_CHECK.ToString();
            textBoxNumberOfFilesMin.Text = FILE_COUNT_CHECK.ToString();

        }
        private void buttonBrowseForFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            textBoxFolderName.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void buttonMakeTree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(textBoxFolderName.Text))
            {
                MyDirectory root = MyDirectory.root;

                TreeNode rootNode = MakeTreeRecursive(textBoxFolderName.Text, root);
                textBoxTotalNumberOfFiles.Text = root.totalNumberOfFiles.ToString();
                textBoxTotalSize.Text = ((long)root.totalSize).ToString();

                if (rootNode == null)
                {
                    string rootNodeText = string.Format("Folder: '{0}', Number of Files: '{1}', File Size: '{2}'",
                        textBoxFolderName.Text,
                        textBoxTotalNumberOfFiles.Text,
                        textBoxTotalSize.Text
                    );
                    rootNode = new TreeNode(rootNodeText);
                }
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                treeView1.ExpandAll();


            }
        }
        private TreeNode MakeTreeRecursive(string folder, MyDirectory myDirectory)
        {
            TreeNode node = null;

            myDirectory.name = folder.Substring(folder.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

            myDirectory.numberOfFiles = 0;
            myDirectory.size = 0.0f;

            try
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fInfo in dInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        float fSize = fInfo.Length;
                        myDirectory.size += fSize;
                        myDirectory.numberOfFiles += 1;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error : Cannot Access File '{0}'", fInfo.Name);
                    }
                }

                myDirectory.totalSize = myDirectory.size;
                myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles = myDirectory.numberOfFiles;
                foreach (string subFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
                {
                    if (myDirectory.children == null) myDirectory.children = new List<MyDirectory>();
                    MyDirectory childDirectory = new MyDirectory();
                    myDirectory.children.Add(childDirectory);

                    TreeNode childNode = MakeTreeRecursive(subFolder, childDirectory);
                    if (childNode != null)
                    {
                        if (node == null)
                        {
                            node = new TreeNode();
                        }
                        node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                    }

                    myDirectory.totalSize += childDirectory.totalSize;
                    myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles += childDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles;
                }
            }
            catch
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error : Cannot Access Folder '{0}'", dInfo.Name);
            }


            if ((myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles >= long.Parse(textBoxNumberOfFilesMin.Text)) || myDirectory.totalSize >= float.Parse(textBoxTotalFolderSizeMin.Text))
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    node = new TreeNode();
                }
                string childNodeText = string.Format("Folder: '{0}', Number of Files: '{1}', File Size: '{2}'",
                    folder,
                    myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles,
                    myDirectory.totalSize
                );
                node.Text =  childNodeText;
            }
            return node;
        }

    }
    public class MyDirectory
    {
        public static MyDirectory root = new MyDirectory();
        public List<MyDirectory> children { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public long totalNumberOfFiles = 0;
        public int numberOfFiles = 0;
        public float size = 0.0f;
        public float totalSize = 0.0f;
    }
}
```